# How do you add up an output given from a log file using Python

Tags: python

I need to output the ammount of attacks, per hour, per IP from a log file using Python script. I have managed to get it all done but can not work out how to add amount of attacks into a final total. I am lacking the knowledge needed to understand how the total function works outside of simple calculations. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
import re
from itertools import groupby
total = 0

with open(log_file) as Authlog:
    Authlog = (line for line in Authlog if "Failed password for" in line)

    for key, group in groupby(Authlog, key = lambda x: x[:9] + re.search('from(.+?) port', x).group(1)):
        hour, month, day = key[0:3], key[4:6], key[7:9]
        print ("Within the hour of %s:00 on %s-%s There was %d attacks"%(day, month, hour, len(list(group))))
        Total = total +1

print("Total amount of attacks: %s" % total)
```

What I expect the result to be:

```
Within the hour of 08:00 on  3-Feb There was 172 attacks
Within the hour of 13:00 on  3-Feb There was 4 attacks
Within the hour of 21:00 on  3-Feb There was 1 attacks
Within the hour of 08:00 on  4-Feb There was 15 attacks
Within the hour of 10:00 on  4-Feb There was 58 attacks
Within the hour of 10:00 on  4-Feb There was 2 attacks
Within the hour of 16:00 on  4-Feb There was 4 attacks
Within the hour of 07:00 on  5-Feb There was 24 attacks
Within the hour of 08:00 on  5-Feb There was 86 attacks
Total amount of attacks: 366
```

What I actually get:

```
Within the hour of 08:00 on  3-Feb There was 172 attacks
Within the hour of 13:00 on  3-Feb There was 4 attacks
Within the hour of 21:00 on  3-Feb There was 1 attacks
Within the hour of 08:00 on  4-Feb There was 15 attacks
Within the hour of 10:00 on  4-Feb There was 58 attacks
Within the hour of 10:00 on  4-Feb There was 2 attacks
Within the hour of 16:00 on  4-Feb There was 4 attacks
Within the hour of 07:00 on  5-Feb There was 24 attacks
Within the hour of 08:00 on  5-Feb There was 86 attacks
Total amount of attacks: 9
```

Comment: Just change your `total = total + 1` to `total = total + len(list(group))`

Comment: Why `Total = total +1`, you should put `total = total +1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable name case does matter. Just change the line:

```
Total = total +1
```

to

```
total = total + len(list(group))
```

because inside a loop your `totals` counter is incorrect: instead it counts just iteration count. And the value **set to a new variable `Total`** created inside each loop step is loosing.

Comment: Thank you, it took a little bit of fiddling and rearranging but that sorted it. I did try this at the start but it still comes back as 0, but with everything in the right place its perfect.